# Merging rows with the same id

Tags: sql

I have many tables in my db which has: RowID,  ProductID and Numeric Value (Numeric value can be NULL, what means infinity).  In table can be many Rows with the same ProductId. Is this possible to make function that take some of this tables (not all, only chosen by me) and return new table which contains all ProductId from each table but there is only one ProductId in table and Numeric Value is sum of all rows from each table. E.g

Table1:

```
RowID   ProductID   Numeric Value    
0       1           1.5    
1       1           3.5    
2       2           4
```

Table2:

```
RowID   ProductID   Numeric Value    
0       1           6    
1       3           1.25
2       3           NULL
```

Return Table:

```
ProductID   Numeric Value    
1           11 (1.5+3.5+6)    
2           4    
3           NULL (1.25 + NULL)
```

*it also can return 0 instead of NULL, all Numeric Values are positive so 0 can represent infinity

Comment: Why do you have several table so similar?

Comment: Which DBMS are using ?

Comment: This is only example. I need this for two types of tables. First type - it is a user fridge which contains all food that user has in fridge. In this scenario it ll be only one input table so i need just to sum all rows with same ID. And second type - it is a meal ingredient which contains ingredient and quantity in recipe. Every user can create many "diets" which contains some of this meal recipe. So i have to take all this diets, and then i have to take all ingredients and make table which has only one ingredient and sum from all recipes

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 1):

I think you can first combine 2 columns and then group them -

```
SELECT PID, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(NV) THEN SUM(NV) ELSE NULL END
FROM (SELECT ProductID PID, Numeric Value NV
      FROM TABLE_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ProductID, Numeric Value
      FROM TABLE_2) T
GROUP BY PID
```

Comment: Note that OP wants sum = null for ProductID 3.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think the sum would ever come as null. SUM function ignore nulls while summing them.

Comment: I'd try `case when count(*) = count(NumVal) then SUM(Numval) end`.

Comment: @jarlh, Thank you soooooo much for giving me this beautiful trick to hack the SUM function. I will surely use this in future whenever needed.

Comment: But how this works on many tables? I have to give tables as parameters and number of this tables can change, it can be 3 or 100. Is this even possible to give many tables as input in function or my whole idea and DB is sh*t? xD also i can do everything in my program by using C# DataTable but I thought making it in sql ll be faster.